# How to display the correct date after adding a number of days to it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-form

I want to display the correct calculated date on a text field in a redux form after getting the number of days to be added from another field in the redux form. Is there any other way to do it? The below method is displying the wrong date i.e the "value" is wrong.

```
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const formName = 'ProcessForm';
      const values = formValueSelector(formName);

      export const ProcessSend: React.FC<Props> = () => {
      
      const formData = useSelector(state => (state as any).form);
      const duration= values({ form: formData }, 'runDays');
      const calculate= () =>{
      const current= new Date();
        let value = new Date(current.setDate(current.getDate()+ duration));
        dispatch(change(formName, 'endsOn', value));
      }
    return (
      <Field
       component={MyComponent}
       name={'runDays'}
       onChange={calculate}/>
      
      <Field
       component={MyComponent}
       name={'endsOn'}
       disabled />
    )

};
```

Comment: I don't understand this line: `values({ form: formData }, 'runDays');`. What does `values` function return?

Comment: have edited the code to include values @GiovanniEsposito

Comment: The date seems to calculate correctly, if duration has a valid number. The bug is most probably outside of provided code.